# Swift animateWithDuration()

Tags: ios, animation, swift

I want to change the imageView's y in an animation and change the text of the label. But when I do that. The ImageView goes up 100 and then does the animation from -100 to 0. But I want it do go down 100.

If I don't change the text of the label, the animation works perfectly.

```
    label.text = "test"

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.imageView.frame.origin.y += 100

    })
```

Also if I do that, it only changes the text and doesn't move the imageView.

```
    label.text = "test"
    imageView.frame.origin.y += 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using AutoLayout. You cannot change the `frame` directly when using auto layout.

You have to set up the constraints and then animate the change in constraints to animate the views.

Also, you can't do `blah.frame.origin.y += 100` IIRC the origin on CGrect is read only.

You can do...

```
Blah.frame = CGRectOffset(blah.frame, 0, 100)
```

But again that won't work with auto layout.

**Edit**

The origin is settable in swift. Thanks jrturton:-)

Comment: The origin is settable using swift

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't sure with swift. Thanks :-)

Comment: So there is no way with AutoLayout and I have do generate the imageView in my code?

Comment: Yes there is a way with AutoLayout. You have to animate the constraints around the view. Have a look on the Ray Wenderlich site. (There are also hundreds of SO questions showing how to do this). Do you have to generate the image view in code? No. You can still do it in IB. You can do it in code and remove auto layout from the image view and this code will work but better to animate it with auto layout.